# How to create Graphics object for drawing Polygon?

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, polygon, java-2d

I need to draw a Polygon - by connecting consecutive points and then connecting the last point to the first.

With this goal I tried to use [drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon%28int%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d,%20int%29). To my mind it's much more convenience approach to achieve this aim

But the `Graphics` class is abstract class and I we can't create instance object and call `drawPolygon()` method?

**Code:**

```
public void draw() {
        Graphics g = null;
        int xPoints [] = new int[pointsList.size()];
        int yPoints [] = new int[pointsList.size()];
        int nPoints = pointsList.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.size(); i++) {
            xPoints [i] = (int) pointsList.get(i).getX();
            yPoints [i] = (int) pointsList.get(i).getY();
        } 

        g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
    }
```

- Can we circumvent calling this method at any way?
- Maybe exist some other ways to achieve this aim?

Comment: **But the Graphics class is abstract class and I we can't create instance object and call drawPolygon() method?** 1. put all `Objects` to the `array`, 2. use `Swing JComponent` or `JPanel` (override `getPreferredSize`), 3. `custom painting` is done in `paintComponent`, 4. inside `paintComponent` to loop inside `arrays of prepared Objects`, 5 use local variables for positioning of `Objects` in `JComponent` or `JPanel`

Comment: Where do you need to render it to? The screen or a file?

Comment: @MadProgrammer to screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem, this was how I circumvented it:

```
//assuming you are displaying your polygon in a JFrame with a JPanel
public class SomeDrawingFrame extends JPanel{
    SomeDrawingFrame(){
    }

    @Override   //JFrame has this method that must be overwritten in order to 
                  display a rendered drawing.

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Polygon square = new Polygon();

        // these points will draw a square
        square.addPoint((0, 0));    //use this.getWidth() method if you want to 
                                         create based on screen size
        square.addPoint((0, 100));
        square.addPoint((100, 100));
        square.addPoint((100, 0)); 
        int y1Points[] = {0, 0, 100, 100};

        g.draw(polygon);
    }
}
```

now just create an instance of this and add it to a JFrame of minimum height and width of 100 each. You can use JFrame's getWidth() method which will return the size of the JFrame and use this to set your points instead (which is better) because then the image will render relative to the size of the frame itself.

Comment: @ChrisMcJava It gives syntax error `The method draw(GeneralPath) is undefined for the type Graphics` for `g.draw(polygon)`. And here `Graphics` is parameter of `Paint`

Comment: You should be using the width & height values of the component it self, as it might be added to another child component and may be under the control of a lay out manager

Answer (score 2):

The reason the developers made Graphics abstract was that a graphics object needs to come from somewhere. For instance a JPanel or JFrame object have a graphics object associated with them since they render viewable areas to the screen. A graphics object is usually assigned with the getGraphics() method. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Polygon extends JFrame {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Test a = new Test();
            a.drawAPolygon();
        }


        public Polygon(){
            setSize(300,300);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        void drawAPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int numPoints){
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, numPoints);
        }
        //@override
            public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            //could also do painting in here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1- You can not rely on getGraphics to return a valid value. 2- The results of getGraphics will be overridden on the repaint cycle 3- You don't actually call drawAPolygon

Answer (score 1):

Painting is controlled by the `RepaintManager`.  Painting in Swing is done via a series of methods which are called on your behalf when the `RepaintManager` decides your component needs to be update (you can, of course, request repaints, but the `RepaintManager` will decided when, what and how much).

In order to perform custom painting in Swing, you need to override one of the methods that are called as part of the paint cycle.

It is [recommended](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks) that you override `paintComponent`

You can check out

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

For more details.

In your example, your `Graphics` is `null`...`Graphics g = null;` which isn't going to help...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimplePloy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimplePloy();
    }

    public SimplePloy() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PloyPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PloyPane extends JPanel {

        private int[] xPoints;
        private int[] yPoints;

        public PloyPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {

            xPoints = null;
            yPoints = null;

            super.invalidate(); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (xPoints == null || yPoints == null) {

                int width = getWidth() - 1;
                int height = getHeight() - 1;

                int halfWidth = width / 2;
                int halfHeight = height / 2;
                int innerWidth = width / 8;
                int innerHeight = height / 8;

                xPoints = new int[9];
                yPoints = new int[9];

                xPoints[0] = halfWidth;
                yPoints[0] = 0;

                xPoints[1] = halfWidth - innerWidth;
                yPoints[1] = halfHeight - innerHeight;  

                xPoints[2] = 0;
                yPoints[2] = halfHeight;

                xPoints[3] = halfWidth - innerWidth;
                yPoints[3] = halfHeight + innerHeight;  

                xPoints[4] = halfWidth;
                yPoints[4] = height;

                xPoints[5] = halfWidth + innerWidth;
                yPoints[5] = halfHeight + innerHeight;  

                xPoints[6] = width;
                yPoints[6] = halfHeight;

                xPoints[7] = halfWidth + innerWidth;
                yPoints[7] = halfHeight - innerHeight;  

                xPoints[8] = halfWidth;
                yPoints[8] = 0;  

            }
            g2d.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: While technically there is truth in the "Painting is controlled by the RepaintManager" sentence, I wouldn't tell a beginner about the RepaintManager, they just don't need to know about it, and I think it confuses them. What should a beginner do with this information? Start studying the RepaintManager API? It wouldn't help much when they only need a Graphics object...

Comment: @lbalazscs The point if mentioning the repaint manager is to inform the OP that they don't have control over the paint process, there is some other system in place, and, yes, I hope they do investigate the repaint manager and how painting works in Swing, it will give them a greater appreciation of how they can benefit from it. One of the problems the OP is having is a lack of knowledge over the paint process